# Distribute quota over a 24 hour time span

Tags: php, time, quota

i've been struggling with a problem for some time know and decided to ask here for help.

Scenario:
In a online game the user has "currency" some users get a bonus of this currency the bonus should be given every day **over a time span** of 24 hours with a dynamic quota. At the end of the day the quota should be given to the user.
The maximum quota is the number of minutes in a day. The currency is not allowed to be increased by more than one each minute. The currency the user currently has is saved in a database is be displayed on a ranking on the page actually the ranking is ordered by this currency

User A has a quota of 100 so he should get 100 of currency a day distributed over time, thats the basic idea distributing a quota over a day

There is a cronjob running every minute, I simulated this and got it working here:

```
$minutesSinceMidnight = 0;
$dailyQuota = 100;
$result = 0;
do {
    if(!($minutesSinceMidnight % floor(1440 / $dailyQuota)))
    {
        $result += 1;
        echo "Minutes since Midnight ".$minutesSinceMidnight. " result ". $result."\n";

    }


    $minutesSinceMidnight += 1;
}
while($minutesSinceMidnight != 1440);

echo "We got ". $result;
```

https://ideone.com/YjjzDG

The problem is this is pretty inaccurate, do you have some suggestions how to solve this better?

Comment: You should probably not be using a cron for this in the first place. You know what time of day it is now, so you can _calculate_ how much of that 100 whatevers the user would have by now.

Comment: I have one limitation the currency is not allowed to be increased by more than one each minute so I thought the cronjob solution would be kinda "ok"

Comment: I added some additional informations

Comment: Well 100 / 1440 is not greater 1, so that should not be a problem. (Or to put it the other way around, as soon as the value goes above 1440, this limitation kinda makes the whole thing not work any more, so you would first of all have to specify what’s supposed to happen in that case then.)

Comment: I think the only thing that makes this a problem for me is the ranking part I forgot to mention and added